# Условия меньше текущей даты

Tags: javascript

помогите по условию.Как выдать ошибку если **this.row** и **this.month** меньше текущей даты, моё условие не работает

```
    var D = new Date();

        if (this.day < D.getDate() && this.month <= D.getMonth() + 1) {
            alert("Назначить тренировку раньше текущей даты - не возможно")
        }
```

Comment: Чему равны this.month и this.day в вашем случае?

Comment: Там ячейки с днем и месяцем, при клике на соответствующую это присваивается this.row и this.month

Comment: Не проще ли вложить день и месяц в Date и сравнивать с текущим временем (``getTime()``)?

Answer (score 2):

В вашем коде есть два обязательных для проверки условия - чтобы и день и месяц были меньше, но может случиться и так, что день будет больше, а месяц меньше. Условие нужно дополнить:

```
    if ( (this.day < D.getDate() && this.month <= D.getMonth() ) || this.month < D.getMonth()) ) {
        console.log("Назначить тренировку раньше текущей даты - не возможно")
    }
```

Comment: К сожалению ваш вариант условия не работает, если дата больше текущей но месяц текущий то все равно выдает ошибку

Comment: this.month < D.getMonth() + 1 - вот так заработало

Comment: Ага, код поправил, тоже к этому пришёл, после очередной проверки ))
У вас проверяемая дата-месяц в другом формате, если нужно делать +1?